# Recovering 1TB hard drive split into two 500GB drives without formatting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

I am using Windows 7 and am trying to recover two working drives.

The hard drive in question was: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822204022

I am pretty sure they were configured with RAID 0 but am not entirely sure.

Anyway, I now have them both plugged in and in the Disk Manager I see:

1. SSD I installed that runs the OS.
2. 500 GB RAW (this one shows via My Computer although when I click it asks me if I want to format)
3. 500 GB Unallocated (Does not show via My Computer)

Now, I am trying to figure out exactly what to do. I tried 'Extending' the drive in the Disk Manager but it tells me I don't have enough space. I looked int he BIOS but couldn't find any raid specific options.

I found a similar thread (http://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?t=14190&start=) and it mentions that the data is interleaved and I should use a software tool to recover it.

What else can I do to get the OS to recognize the drives as one continuous drive?

I also have access to EaseUS Partition Wizard from work but would only want to use this as a last option.

How can I get the OS to recognize both of these drives as one drive and access my data?

Comment: If this is data you care about, don't do anything until you take a full image of both 500GB drives.

Comment: The problem with RAID-0 is that your data is spanned across multiple disks for performance but no redundancy. If your array degrades in any way such as removing a disk or changing part of a disk where the other isn't aware of the change can cause the entire array to fail. You need to get the array back together using the original configuration but don't initialise a NEW array. Did you use your BIOS to create the array or Windows/your OS?

Comment: @BigChris No. it was set up by the company that shipped it. If I theoretically enable them as RAID 0 drives and nothing has been damaged, they should work, correct? It's possible that my machine (which is a server machine) doesn't support RAID 0 drives.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want the 1 TB hdd to run as one partition you need to do this:

If you choose to go with this option be sure to click on the 500 GB of unallocated space and hit delete to make sure that the expand option will work on the original 500 GB that is already "installed".

1. Right click My computer and hit Manage.
2. Click disk management, in there you will see the 500 GB unallocated space.
3. Click on the existing 500 GB partition that you already see in My Computer and hit expand. In doing this the setup wizard will automatically see the remaining 500 GB unallocated space and just hit next until you finish the process.
4. You're done and now you should see all the space in one partition.

This process will NOT affect any of your existing files located in the original 500 GB partition. Post here if you have any more problems/questions regarding this topic.

Second option :

Click on your 500 GB of unallocated space and hit format, you will be prompted to assign a letter to that partition and then finish the setup.

Comment: I had "with formatting" written in the title when I wanted "without". Corrected.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I do have data on both of these drives. I essentially gamble if I delete the second drive and extend and can theoretically lose up to 500gb of my data. I really don't want to do this.

Comment: Can you clarify that deleting the unallocated space and then expanding using it will not delete the files?